# Autodesk Forge - Viewer Blank on Ipad

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are not able to open models using the forge viewer on an iPad (using safari and chrome).  When we open the model, we are just getting a blank page.  The console logs this error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.visibility Manager')".  Attaching a screenshot showing the full stack trace:[image: Console Stack Trace]

The same application loads correctly on desktop browsers.

I'm also sending a sample of the file as well as an application link to forge support.

iOS Version 14.3
Forge Viewer version 7.53.0

Comment: Just to narrow down the possible causes, have you tried opening another Forge app on the iPad? For example, can you load https://forge-basic-app.herokuapp.com and view models there? Also, try removing the viewer extensions you're using, and bring them back one at a time, to see if one of them could be causing the failure.

Comment: Btw. I just tried opening the link to your demo/sample on my iPhone XS (iOS 14.7.1), and it loaded without problems...

Comment: Petr, I was able to open the forge-basic-app example, but was still getting the same result for the O3 demo.  Today I updated my iPad to iOS 15.0.2, and now I can open the forge viewer in both applications,  so It appears the issue was specific to the older iOS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to iOS 15.0.2 solved this issue.  It also appears to work on iOS 14.7.1.